# what I use Encryption and not Encrypt on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In last version on CodeIgniter I used function `decode()`

I used :

```
if($row->accesso == 1 && $row->username == $username $$ $this->obj->encrypt->decode("$row->password") == $password )
```

But in php 7.2 `mcrypt` is removed. If I use `encrypt` or `decrypt` of Encryption library i have an error to login. I can't enter in my page. Can you help me ?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Why not use **PHP hashing** that has a decryption function too such as `password_hash` etc.. Also there are lot of hashing library on the web that you can use.

Comment: I need correct only this code , please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `password_hash`/`password_verify`:

**TEST:**

Try to create first the user's password by using `password_hash()` then store it on the database manually,

```
password_hash('password123', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

It will output like : `$2y$10$8UgJIh.KAnDc1/b.4gb33eaBtrDRgXb2kQt8oNO0GKRe6sIFKR8IC`

Then to verify, you can use `password_verify()` to check if the user's password input is equal to the `hashed password` in the database. Use `if else statement` for this function. `password_verify()` also returns true for every matched hashed strings. (Let's assume that `$password = 'password123'` and `$hashed_password = $2y$10$8UgJIh.KAnDc1/b.4gb33eaBtrDRgXb2kQt8oNO0GKRe6sIFKR8IC` so the checking will be:

```
if(password_verify($password,$hashed_password)) { successful login } else { failure }
```

You can read more about [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) for more further explanation.

This is only an example, it might not work on your current code because it seems you used other hashing function. Hope this helps!